# Converting physics example to Velocity Verlet / Leapfrog method

Tags: physics, python, integration

I'm looking at the [impressive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS_qeBy3aQI) about verlet integration.
I managed to implement a sphere falling, exactly like the video up to the minute mark 2:19 in the video.

I want to use velocity verlet instead. After looking at some examples, it's not going to well. All the examples I could find have poor variable names and are not made as objective programming with a solver class.

Here is the falling ball python code.

```
import weakref
import numpy as np

dt = 1.0
frames = 10

class verlet_obj:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, position_current):
        self.position_current = position_current
        self.position_old = position_current
        self.acceleration = np.zeros(3)
        self.velocity = np.zeros(3)

        #reference self via weakref
        self.__class__.instances.append(weakref.proxy(self))
    
    def updatePosition(self, dt):
        self.velocity = self.position_current - self.position_old

        self.position_old = self.position_current

        # perform velvet 
        self.position_current = self.position_current + self.velocity + self.acceleration * dt * dt

        # reset acceleration 
        self.acceleration = 0

    def accelerate(self, acceleration): 
        self.acceleration += acceleration

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        self.gravity = np.array([0, -9.8, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.apply_gravity()
        self.updatePositions()

    def updatePositions(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.updatePosition(self.dt)

    def apply_gravity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.accelerate(self.gravity)

# run 
solver = Solver(dt)
sphere1 = verlet_obj(np.array([0,0,0]))
for frame in range(0,frames):
    solver.update()
    # print y pos
    print(sphere1.position_current[1])
```

my attempt is to follow this [source](https://www2.icp.uni-stuttgart.de/%7Eicp/mediawiki/images/5/54/Skript_sim_methods_I.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1dA6sWSf22mnoUN-fsQ5ju2IPVi2IM9InjUoSbZiEJ0epeSh6Qu8uw0kU):
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
import weakref
import numpy as np
from sg_blender import *
dt = 1
frames = 11

class verlet_obj:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, position_current):
        self.position_current = position_current
        self.position_old = position_current
       
        self.velocity_old = np.zeros(3)  
        self.velocity_intermediate = np.zeros(3)
        self.velocity_current = np.zeros(3)
        self.acceleration = np.zeros(3)

        #reference self via weakref
        self.__class__.instances.append(weakref.proxy(self))
    
    def updatePosition(self, dt):
        self.position_old = self.position_current
        self.position_current = self.position_current + self.velocity_old + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt**2 

    def updateVelocityIntermediate(self, dt):
        self.velocity_intermediate = self.velocity_old + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt

    def accelerate(self, acceleration): 
        self.acceleration += acceleration
    
    def reset_acceleration(self):
        self.acceleration = np.zeros(3)
    
    def new_velocity(self, dt):
        self.velocity_current = self.velocity_intermediate + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt
        self.velocity_old = self.velocity_current

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        self.gravity = np.array([0, -9.8, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.new_positions() # step 2
        self.intermidate_velocity() # step 3
        self.reset_acceleration() #step 4
        self.apply_gravity() #step 4
        self.new_velocity() #step 5


    def new_positions(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.updatePosition(self.dt)

    def reset_acceleration(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.reset_acceleration()

    def intermidate_velocity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.updateVelocityIntermediate(self.dt)

    def new_velocity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.new_velocity(self.dt)

    def apply_gravity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.accelerate(self.gravity)

# run 

solver = Solver(dt)
sphere1 = verlet_obj(np.array([0,0,0]))
for frame in range(0,frames):
    solver.update()
    # print y pos
    print(sphere1.position_current[1])
```

I'm not sure if I understand the concept of `dt` correctly, but after 10 iterations, I get the y position as -440.
But according to falling in constant acceleration kinematic equation, this is not correct.

```
x = x_0 + v_0 * t + 1/2 * a t^2
# zero start height, zero start speed 
# ==> 
x = 1/2 * a t^2
x = 1/2 * - 9.8 * 10**2
  = -490
```

Comment: "it's not going to well." what kind of error did you encounter when you tried to implement it? You can post your non working code as well

Comment: Thanks @Zibelas I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Maybe there are too many functions and it needs some clean up. But after testing the anaytic function of an object in free fall `x = 1/2 * a * t^2` and the result, I noticed my result changed drastically with the time-step parameter. `dt` was missing in step 2 (calculate new position).

Here is the result of `dt = 1` , free falling of 15 seconds:

[image]

and `dt = 0.1`

[image]

Code: ( yes needs some clean up )

```
import weakref
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dt* frames = 15 seconds
scale = 10
frames = 15*scale
dt = 1.0/scale

class verlet_obj:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, position_current):
        self.position_current = position_current
        self.position_old = position_current

        self.velocity_old = np.zeros(3)
        self.velocity_intermediate = np.zeros(3)
        self.velocity_current = np.zeros(3)
        self.acceleration = np.zeros(3)

        self.__class__.instances.append(weakref.proxy(self))

    def updatePosition(self, dt):
        self.position_current = self.position_old + self.velocity_old * dt + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt**2

    def updateVelocityIntermediate(self, dt):
        self.velocity_intermediate = self.velocity_old + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt

    def accelerate(self, acceleration):
        self.acceleration += acceleration

    def reset_acceleration(self):
        self.acceleration = np.zeros(3)

    def new_velocity(self, dt):
        self.velocity_current = self.velocity_intermediate + 0.5 * self.acceleration * dt
        self.velocity_old = self.velocity_current
        self.position_old = self.position_current

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        self.gravity = np.array([0, -9.8, 0])

    def update(self):
        self.new_positions() # step 2
        self.intermidate_velocity() # step 3
        self.reset_acceleration() #step 4
        self.apply_gravity() #step 4
        self.new_velocity() #step 5

    def new_positions(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.updatePosition(self.dt)

    def reset_acceleration(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.reset_acceleration()

    def intermidate_velocity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.updateVelocityIntermediate(self.dt)

    def new_velocity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.new_velocity(self.dt)

    def apply_gravity(self):
        for obj in verlet_obj.instances:
            obj.accelerate(self.gravity)

# run code and check with analyic 
solver = Solver(dt)
sphere1 = verlet_obj(np.array([0,0,0]))
y_sim = []
for frame in range(0,frames):
    solver.update()
    y_sim.append(sphere1.position_current[1])

x_sim = np.arange(0, 15, dt)
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
y = - 1/2 * 9.8 * x**2

plt.plot(x,y, label = "analytic")
plt.plot(x_sim,y_sim, label = "velocity verlet")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```